# CFHTTPCookieGetCreateDate is deprecated in this OS build (iOS4)

Tags: iphone, cookies, ios4, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest

I have a simple application which accesses cookies from a webpage using a standard NSURLConnection.  The existing version of the application works fine (developed for 3.0), however, I have modified the app (making it fully iOS4 compatible) and I now recieve the following warning in the log:

> > CFHTTPCookieGetCreateDate is deprecated in this OS build.  Clients must call CFHTTPCookieGetCreationTime or the NS equivalent instead or risk leaks.

The application still works fine, but I'm concerned about "leaks", any ideas???  I can't find "CFHTTPCookieGetCreateDate" in my application!

I think the issue occurs in:

```
- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
self.responseData = [NSMutableData data];

// information returned from the cookie
NSDictionary *headerFields = [(NSHTTPURLResponse*)response allHeaderFields]; 
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

//Cookies Array 
cookies = [NSHTTPCookie cookiesWithResponseHeaderFields:headerFields forURL:url];

headerPointsTotal = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", [cookies objectAtIndex:2]];

}
```

Thanks,

Comment: i am having same issue . .. have u found soln for this....

Comment: Nope!  Just ignored it and released the app to the app store anyway.  Have not received any negative feedback which suggests it is causing issues!

Answer (score 1):

deprecated only means that you should be carefully on using it. It means that in further iOS versions this method may be removed and then you would have a crash.

just for interest you can set your deployment target to 4.0 only and see if this appears again. Otherwise (if this is not related to your code) you can ignore it.